# CollapseAppbar + Image Overlay (The system theme)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I was using the Default "CollapsingAppbar" then, after observing some design, i started wondering how can make the layout works in this way, with the imageview overlay the "Statusbar", where we can see notifications, battery and so on.

[First Example](https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*rd979yYprZ-bqsU3j98boQ.png)

[Second example](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_FfNcpiMcRY/VsdukdyfUUI/AAAAAAAAEy8/AiMQ4K5fNh0/s320/Screenshot_2016-02-19-21-32-24%255B2%255D.png)

> Here is my XML with no sucess

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Application.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"

                android:src="@drawable/street_map"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Application.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivities.StoreActivity" >

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Monday" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tuesday" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Wednesday" />
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> And here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.application">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Application.NoActionBar">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivities.SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivities.StoreActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivities.MainActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to change the Appbar with Overlay THEME, but no sucess, and i did the same with the toolbar with PopupOverlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! after some attempts it fixed by himself, hehehe.
Humm!, I think it was because i put a lot of elements with:

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
> and maybe...
> android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"